# Where to set JDK to be used for SunOne server?

Tags: solaris, java, java-home, sunone

Where to set the JDK to be used by the SunOne server on Solaris?

Is it all configured via an environment variable like JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME, or is there a config file for the SunOne server somewhere where the path to the JDK is being set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All startup scripts of this kind should at least be based on the JAVA_HOME environment variable, that you can [set on Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19062-01/sun.mgmt.ctr36/817-7958/6mn891leo/index.html).

You can look if you fond a '.cfg' file in which you may define the same variable: the [Sun ONE Studio Solaris installation](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tools/deployment/solinstall_j2eedeployapi.html) page does reference one (but that is for *Studio*).
Of you could edit directly the script used to run the server, in its 'bin' directory.

But if there is no config file, you can simply make a script ([like this one](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5022278)) to wrap the startup sequence and define that variable.
That way, your .profile can still define a JDK while your 'SunOne Server start' script uses another.